# Array.filter is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array and i want to remove a record from it i have use `Array.filter()` but its return same array as it is.

My Code:

```
var url = window.location.pathname,
    orderId = url.split('/').slice(-2)[0];
var Cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Cart'));
newCart=Cart.filter(function(item) {
    if (parseInt(item.orderId) == parseInt(orderId)) {
        return {};
    }
    else
    {
        return item;
    }
});
localStorage.setItem('Cart',JSON.stringify(newCart));
```

Comment: the return from the function in array.filter should be true or false, true to "keep" the item in the output array, false to to "skip" it - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You **should return** `true` or `false` in the filter in order to filter data from an array.
Return `true` to add the element in the filtered list, `false` otherwise.
So you can do something like this using **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

```
newCart = Cart.filter(function(item) {
    return parseInt(item.orderId, 10) != parseInt(orderId, 10);
});
```