# Filter is not returning the first element of the array, even though console.log says it is

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Given two arrays of integers, I want to make a new array with just the unique values of the two input arrays. I know there are a bunch of different ways to do this, but I'm interested in why the way I'm trying to do it is not working.

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr2 = [2, 3, 1, 0, 5];

// combine both arrays
const combined = arr1.concat(arr2);

// sort combined array
combined.sort();

// fitler out elements identical to the preceding element
const result = combined.filter((el, i, a) => {

  if ( (el != a[i-1]) ) {
    console.log("return", el);
    return el;
  }
});

// print
console.log(result);
```

Even though zero is part of the combined array, the output is [1,2,3,4,5]. When I console.log it, I definitely see that my filter method is returning element zero, but for some reason it doesn't show up in the result array. What's wrong?

Comment: I am not sure on that, but could it be possible that filter adds nothing if the method returns 0 and just thinks its NULL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array.filter is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437396/array-filter-is-not-working-properly)

Comment: `.filter()` filters out values depending on whether the callback function returns `true` or `false`. You return `el`, which is a number and `0` is a falsy value. Change the callback to `(el, i, a) => el != a[i-1]`.

Comment: As other people said, when you return the value `0`, the filter function take that value as a `false`. You can see more info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920037/why-does-array-filternumber-filter-zero-out-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda in the `filter` must return a boolean value ([thruthy or falsy](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)). `0` is considered falsy, so the value will not be in the result.

Maybe you don't need a loop after all: a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) weeds out the duplicate values.

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr2 = [2, 3, 1, 0, 5];

// use Set
console.log(JSON.stringify([...new Set(arr1.concat(arr2))]));

// or filter with a lambda that returns true/false
const result = arr1.concat(arr2).sort().filter((val, i, a) => val !== a[i-1]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```